# htaccess redirect dynamic url to one with hashbang

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have `http://domain.com/frame/1234sdfs` but I want to change it to `http://domain.com/#/frame/1234sdfs`

I'm using trial and error at the moment and getting nowhere with the following in my .htaccess

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/frame/([^/]*)$ /#/frame/$1`

Could someone place me in the right direction? I have been using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to try get the output URL as expected but can't figure it out.

Comment: How is it not working? Are no redirects being processed at all (perhaps a web-server configuration issue), or is only this redirect not working.  Why do you want to redirect to URL with `#` in it?  This character has very special meaning in URL's - typically meaning that is only understood within a client browser, not at the server.  So unless you have some special reason to use this character, I would warn against it.

Comment: @MikeBrant I recently set up an AngularJS site on Google Compute Engine. I need any previous calls to `/frame/{uniqueID}` to be forwarded to have a hashbang.

Comment: Your rule is right and should work from your site root .htaccess or Apache config

Comment: So, I don't know why being on Google Compute Engine would really make any difference in resolving this problem. So, let me elaborate on the key question from my earlier comment. Are any rewrites working (i.e. is mod_rewrite even enabled)?  If so, are directory-specific overrides enabled in your Apache configuration (i.e. to even allow an .htaccess file to be used)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod_rewrite so that you can use the `NE` flag. It's probably being converted to `%23` using `mod_alias`. You need to send it *literally* with this code here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^frame/([^/]+)/?$ /#/frame/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

> Omitting the [NE] will result in the # being converted to its hexcode
>   equivalent, %23, which will then result in a 404 Not Found error
>   condition.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Note: **Makes sure .htaccess is allowed and mod_rewrite is enabled.**